# Want to store every iterated data in an array

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facepy

```
import json
import time
import urllib
from pymongo import MongoClient
from facepy import GraphAPI

access_token = 'EAACEdEose0cBAKrXodSbgJM32aihWYeFwnm3X8i2CPB7Pn4L2fujnNDc49pGwuV4pqccHxsX2ooudEVRGRAGe7mDZAB0mlZCGFO12cW78klPGjVeanTaJjwZCuNek8BsQRisUeUh7CijjOyTReVybj0EeZAZBBpf0Y099uE9pBgZDZD'
graph = GraphAPI(access_token,version= '2.8')

def counts():
    posts= "no likes"
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.fb
    collection = db.check
    query = db.posts.find()
    for q in query:
            liker_id = "null"
            liker_name = "null"
            likes = "no likes in the post"
            id = q['post_id']
            response=graph.get(id+'?fields=likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true),shares')
            if 'likes' in response:
                for d in response['likes']['data']:
                     liker_id = d['id']
                     liker_name = d['name']
                     for i in liker_id:
                          posts = {"id":[liker_id]}
                post = {"post_id":id,"likes":posts}
                print post
counts()

{'post_id': u'256015257837672_1017155801723610', 'likes': {'id': [u'905803702763261']}}
{'post_id': u'256015257837672_1016685905103933', 'likes': {'id': [u'808269765904912']}}
```

**I AM GETTING ONLY THE LAST LIKER_ID IN THE OUTPUT BUT I WANT TO STORE ALL THE LIKER_ID IN THAT LIKES SECTION 
PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS THANKING YOU**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can simply done by appending the post as an array so it will get all the data in an array

```
posts = []  
tmp = {"likerId":liker_id,"likername":liker_name}
posts.append(tmp)
```